# Why can a function be usable in determined range?

Tags: python, list

I've been learning Python since a while and developing a function for doing a list of [Lucky numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number) i made this code:

```
def lucky(n):

    list = []
    rem1 = []
    rem2 = []

    # First verification

    for i in range(1,n+1,2):
        list.append(i)

    print (list)

    # Second verification

    for i in range(2,m,3):
        element = list[i]
        rem1.append(element)

    list = [x for x in list if x not in rem1]

    # Third verification

    n=(len(list))+1

    for i in range(6,n,7):
        element = list[i]
        rem2.append(element)

    list = [x for x in list if x not in rem2]

    return list
```

My problems begins when running values bigger than 55. Why can Python take as out of range the code after that specific number and how could it be corrected?

Comment: What is `m` in `for i in range(2,m,3):`?

Comment: What you've written here is not how lucky numbers are generated.  You've implemented only the first three stages of a process that needs to continue for as long as numbers are being removed from the list.  Apparently, 55 is the point at which a fourth stage is needed for correct output; you'd eventually need a fifth stage, and so on.  (Also, using `list` as a variable name is a horrible idea - you've overridden a very fundamental built-in object.)

Comment: The `m` here should be `n`: `for i in range(2,m,3):`, probably there will be an `IndexError: list index out of range` for the line `element = list[I]`, that means `i` is larger than `len(list) -1`, that's because in the first loop you're jumping by two elements and in the second loop you're jumping by 3 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The word "list" is a reserved word in python, you should change the name to a non-reserved word.
2. You have a type on line 16: `for i in range(2,m,3):` that "m" should be an "n", should it not?
3. The range you use in your second for loop exceeds the length of the list object.  You need to check the length with an if statement.

   ```
   for i in range(2,n,3):
       if len(my_list) > i:
           element = my_list[i]
           rem1.append(element)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Reading in a [math web](https://oeis.org/A000959), i found this problem.

It is solved with this code:

```
    def lucky(n):   
    # Lista inicial
    lista = list(range(1, n + 1, 2))
    # Variable inicial
    indice = 1
    # Ciclo de ejecución
    while indice <= len(lista) - 1 and lista[indice] <= len(lista):
        lista = [Li for i, Li in enumerate(lista) if (i + 1) % lista[indice]]
        indice += 1
    # Resultados
    return lista
```

My question here is about how is line 8 working

Comment: It's called a list comprehension, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html see section 5.1.3.